# Displaying Rectangles on External Screen

Tags: ios, swift, external-display

I already have labels displaying on my externals screen but I want to add a blue rectangle of Width: 500px and Height: 50px.

What would be the code to add this?

This is the code I use for my Label.

```
var secondWindow: UIWindow!
var secondScreenView: UIView!

@objc func setupScreen(){
    if UIScreen.screens.count > 1{
        let secondScreen = UIScreen.screens[1]

        secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: secondScreen.bounds)

        let viewController = UIViewController()
        secondWindow!.rootViewController = viewController

        secondWindow!.screen = secondScreen

        secondScreenView = UIView(frame: secondWindow!.frame)

        secondWindow!.addSubview(secondScreenView)

        secondWindow!.isHidden = false

        // CUSTOMISE VIEW
        secondScreenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // BATTING TEAM NAME - EXTERNAL
        battingTeamNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 80.0)
        battingTeamNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
        battingTeamNameLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:50, y:10)
```

Comment: You already know how to add views and labels to your second window. What issue are you having adding one more view with a blue background?

Comment: I’m wanting to put my label text within a Blue rectangle. Sorry if it’s a stupid question 

Comment: Put your label in inside a `UIView` and set the view's background color

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. What if I want the rectangle to be a different size though? (eg. Bigger than my label. I was thinking if I can create the rectangle separate it would be easier.

Comment: Yes, the `UIView` is the rectangle.  Size it however you want. Add the `UILabel` as a sub-view and set its constraints to position it how you want.

Comment: So I would be putting a UIView inside a UIView? I already have my main UIView which is White.